# Rendering tiles at a larger size for a detailed look

Tags: rendering, tilemap, tiles, pygame, image-processing

I'm trying to make my 32-bit tiled map become more "zoomed" in. However, I experience an error that I can't resolve. Firstly, I followed [this post on how to render the tiles larger](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/152182/how-can-i-make-tiny-sprites-larger).

**This is my code** *(close to identical to the code in the other post)*:

```
class TiledMap:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        tm = pytmx.load_pygame(filename, pixelalpha=True)
        self.width = tm.width * tm.tilewidth 
        self.height = tm.height * tm.tileheight
        
        self.tmxdata = tm

    def render(self,surface):
        ti = self.tmxdata.get_tile_image_by_gid
        for layer in self.tmxdata.visible_layers:
            if isinstance(layer,pytmx.TiledTileLayer):
                for x,y,gid in layer:
                    tile = ti(gid)
                    tile = pg.transform.scale(tile,(64,64))       <---------- Line that gives Error
                    if tile:
                        surface.blit(tile,(x * 64, y * 64))


    def make_map(self):
        temp_surface = pg.Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.render(temp_surface)
        return temp_surface
```

The error that is produced is:

```
tile = pg.transform.scale(tile,(64,64))
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not None
```

I'm suspecting that some tile that its trying to render simply is empty. I've tried a separate smaller map but the issue persists. Is it the tileset? They've all been processed through the program Tiled where they were initially part of one png.
If anyone knows a possible solutions I'll gladly try one. Or any other methods that could make it more zoomed in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in my case was simple, check if the tile is 'None'. If yes, then pass it, but if not, transform it to a larger size. This is the full code that should be used:

```
class TiledMap:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        tm = pytmx.load_pygame(filename, pixelalpha=True)
        self.width = tm.width * tm.tilewidth 
        self.height = tm.height * tm.tileheight
        
        self.tmxdata = tm

    def render(self,surface):
        ti = self.tmxdata.get_tile_image_by_gid
        for layer in self.tmxdata.visible_layers:
            if isinstance(layer,pytmx.TiledTileLayer):
                for x,y,gid in layer:
                
                    tile = ti(gid)
                    if not tile == None:                     <---- This is the change
                        tile = pg.transform.scale(tile,(64,64))
                        if tile:
                            surface.blit(tile,(x * 64, y * 64))


    def make_map(self):
        temp_surface = pg.Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.render(temp_surface)
        return temp_surface
```

This solution worked for me. Although, i did notice i have to change the camera class as it still limits itself to the 32-bit size.